# Error bounds when approximating densities

Tags: density-function, approximation

I was curious whether it is possible to obtain approximation error bounds on continuous densities from approximation error bounds of random variables.

To make my question more precise: We consider two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with continuous densities $g_X(z)$ and $g_Y(z)$.

When knowing $|X(\omega) - Y(\omega)|<\varepsilon$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, is there a way to bound $|g_X(z)-g_Y(z)|$? Is there any literature on this?